# how to run background Thread that needs to access to ui thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

I am looking forward to add a mouse position checking module on my program.
UI has two `Textbox` to print X and Y. It should print cursor position asynchronously.

I tried with `BeginInvoke`/`Invoke`,`Thread.isBackgroud = true`, `BackgroundWorker` but non of these helped.

Thread/BackgroundWorker is keep occurring

> Cross-Thread error(as expected),

and `BeginInvoke`/`Invoke` has problem with async : UI thread keeps dieing.

I also tried `mousemove` event, this works but when cursor gets out of Form boundary, position tracking stops.

```
delegate void MP();
private void tracktoggle() {
    MP mp = printMousePosition;
    BeginInvoke(mp); // Or Invoke(mp);
}

private void printMousePosition() {
    while(true) {
       this.Xtext.Text = Mouseposition.X.ToString();
       this.Ytext.Text = Mouseposition.Y.ToString();
    }
}
```

this code leaves UI thread on block.

```
private async void tracktoggle() {
    Task T = new Task(() => { printMousePosition(); });
    await T;
}

private void printMousePosition() {
    while(true) {
       this.Xtext.Text = Mouseposition.X.ToString();
       this.Ytext.Text = Mouseposition.Y.ToString();
    }
}
```

this is code with async/await. Doesn't block the UI thread but textboxes were not getting updated.
I thought BeginInvoke was async version of Invoke :( doesn't working

Want to print mouse position asynchronously without blocking the UI thread.

Comment: Well the infinite `while` loop in `printMousePosition()` which you `BeginInvoke` will just result in freezing the UI completely.  You might want to replace your design with a `BackgroundWorker` that reports progress.  Much easier

Comment: ㄴ thanks, I'll retry with the BackgroundWorker set

Comment: You are right though about the `BeginInvoke` being async.  However whatever method it ends up calling must not be an endless loop.  It must give the UI a chance to update itself

Comment: ㄴ oh.. ok I see the point

Comment: `how to run background Thread that needs to access to ui thread` you can use the async await pattern and it takes care of the continuation.

Comment: ㄴ I made code with async, but doesn't updates the textbox

Comment: Research SynchronizationContext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the best solution is to set WindowsHook with user32.dll.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)] 
public static extern int SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)] 
public static extern int CallNextHookEx(int idHook, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

///On the Code 14 is low level mouse hooking id
HookID = SetWindowsHookEx(14, MouseEventFunc, (IntPtr)0, 0/*should be 0, cause we are trying to make global hook);

private void int MouseEventFunc(int nCode, IntPtr w, IntPtr l) {
{
     this.MouseX.Text = MousePosition.X.ToString();
     this.MouseY.Text = MousePosition.Y.ToString();
     return CallNextHookEx(HookID, nCode, w, l);
}
```

this snippet gets / updates the TextBox very well.

Anybody has problem with this issue, try this solution